# Vue.js equivalent of appendChild to dynamically add new element/component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js, I have a `var app = new Vue({...});` and I have a component `Vue.component('mycomponent', ...` where I can use such component  without any issue by directly adding `<mycomponent></mycomponent>` in html. What I wish to do is to dynamically add those component on demand maybe after a button click or when some other such event takes place. In raw JS, I'd use `document.createElement...` when event fires and then do `el.appendChild..` to add it into html. How would I do the same with Vue.js ?

I'm not doing anything fancy with node js. This is on a single html page with `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>` in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this the "Vue way" usually involves the use of [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html), [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) or [`<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), depending on what you want to do:

- Use `v-if` to conditionally show a component/element based on a condition.
- Use `v-for` to render a list of components/elements.
- Use `<component>` to render a dynamic component/element.

So to achieve what you described in your question, you can declare a boolean data property `visible` like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    visible: false
  }
}
```

and use it with `v-if` to control the visibility of a component in the template:

```vue
<mycomponent v-if="visible"></mycomponent>
```

This requires that `<mycomponent>` exist in the template upfront. If you don't know what kind of component you want to show, then you can either include each possibility in the template and display the one you want based on some condition:

```vue
<comp1 v-if="comp1Visible"></comp1>
<comp2 v-if="comp2Visible"></comp2>
<comp3 v-if="comp3Visible"></comp3>
```

or you can use `<component>` together with another data property (`comp`) which you can set to the name of the component you want to display:

```vue
<component v-if="visible" :is="comp"></component>
```

What you described (`document.createElement` followed by `el.appendChild`) does not exist in Vue. Vue has a strict rendering mechanism which you need to work with; it isn't possible to dynamically instantiate components and stick them into the DOM randomly. *Technically* you can do `comp = new Vue()` as an equivalent to `document.createElement` and then `el.appendChild(comp.$el)`, but that probably isn't what you want to do because you would be creating an independent Vue instance that you would have to manage manually with no easy way of passing data around.